# using cycle with unknown number of entries

Tags: cycle

I'm using cycle to open and close a div for a row of content. It works great when there are more than a certain number of entries - in this case 4, but doesn't work when there are fewer than that. Is there a way to make this work so it always closes the div even if there are fewer entries than specified in the code?

```
{{ cycle(['<div class="row">', '', '', ''], loop.index0) | raw }}
... stuff....
{{ cycle(['', '', '', '</div>'], loop.index0) | raw }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I usually solve this problem, notice the explicit check for the last element in the list. You can set `cols` to whatever number of columns you want.

```
{% set cols = 4 %}
{% for thing in things %}
  {% if loop.index0 % cols == 0 %}
    <div class="row">
  {% endif %}
  {# other stuff #}
  {% if (loop.index0 % cols == cols - 1 or loop.last) %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can use Twig's batch for this?

[Twig Batch](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/batch.html)

```
{% set items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'] %}
{% for row in items|batch(3, '') %}
<div class="row">
    {% for column in row %}
        <p>{{ column }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Batch lets you have something to fall back on when you have less items. In this case there are 3 items within my row and if there will be 2, it will output what I have in the '', in this case nothing. (but I can put what I want in that '').

Comment: Nice! Just when you think you have a good handle on all the cool stuff Twig does, you forget there's ``batch``...